# connect windows login with c# program?

Tags: .net, sql-server

I have a c# program that is connected to a database and in the database i have `SalesPersonID` column **(with a number for an example 124547)**. I have multiple windows for user accounts. Is there any way to connect a login window with a c# program so it "knows" which `SalesPersonID` is in use at the moment. It should work like this: i´m connected to my windows account (John Black,pass-user name and password) and now im working in my program (I´m selling stuff).When i make a sale the program should automatically know which user i am (based on my windows login) and it "knows" which `SalesPersonID` I have in my database so that the database with `SalesRecords` gets automatically updated with my `SalesPersonID` number. I hope it's clear what i´m trying to do. I don´t have any idea how to begin with this or if it´s even possible. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this is possible. You can get your current Windows logon username from the system:

```
string userName = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
```

Note that if you are in a domain, this could be of the DOMAIN\username format.

Next, in your database, you create a table (or use your existing users table) to store the Windows login for each of those users. Something like --

```
UserId        WindowsLoginName  
------------  ------------------
55            SALES\JohnBlack
```

(assuming your login name is "JohnBlack" and you are in a domain called "SALES", this is mapped to the User table row where your account has the Id value of "55" -- just assuming all of this).

In your program all you need to do is look up the current value of "userName" (as above) in the table's "WindowsLoginName" column and use the associated Id value :)

Comment: Thanks for your help, but i don´t exactly know hoe to do that. I have to use existing user table and there i should have separate firstname and lastname with a primary key that is social security number. My windows logon is PC2\John and it´s been added to sql server. The problem is how to connect for an example PC2\John with is´s primary key in the table where his name is divided into first and last name. i don´t know how to map this

Comment: i have a user called PC2\John in my login folder in sql server (which is connected with my windows account). i have to somehow map it to the UserID in my SalesStaff table and to be able to pull out his ID from my c# program. For an example i have a program to issue a bill for the purchase and it´s connected to the database. when i press "print the bill" button it should print out the bill with the userID number on it, which i should get from the server. So if the John is logged on to windows his userID should be 14546, for Jack is 345565, for an example.

Comment: I see this has been marked as answer, but did you get this working? Let me know if you still need assistance.

Comment: Well yes and no :) i had to create a login column in a user table so i can "ask" the c# program is the current user = loginname and from that i could pull out the name or userid. But originally what i wanted to do is if the user is admin on my windows account and is admin in my database admin group than he can do certain things and if in user group than he cant do this. And it should be automatically based on the user type.

Comment: Now i have to change the code every time the user gets added.i wanted it to be like if the user is in admin group he can do that and i can add as many admins as i want and they all would have same privileges

Comment: You can still do that. If you are in a domain-based environment, you can query ADSI for the group membership of the user. Similarly you can ask SQL Server.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I will leave it like this for the time being. I´m afraid my programming skills are not that good to do something like that. wouldn´t even know where to start :)